# Installation failed on deploying Xamarin.Forms APK to customer’s devices

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am experiencing an issue of installation of Xamarin.Forms Aapp into customer’s Android devices;
APK installation failed on Android devices under Android 9.0

I developed a Xamarin.Forms app with Visual Studio 2019 and set target android versions as the followings;

```
Compile Using Android Version (Target Framework) - 9.0  
Target Android Version - 9.0  
Minimum Android Version - 5.0
```

I set android options as the followings and built release mode, archived and signed output APK.

```
Use Share Runtime - off
Bundle assemblies into native code - on
aapt2 - on
Multi-Dex- On
Dex Compiler - D8
Code Shrinker - None
Enable developer instrumentation (debugging and profiling) - on
AOT - On
LLVM Optimization Compiler - On
Enable Startup Tracing - On
```

The output APK was installed well on my test Android 5.0.1 device.

However, it was not installed at other android devices under Android 9.0. It was installed well on Android 9.0 devices.

I found that my test Android 5.0.1 device had Xamarin.Android API-28 Support module, because I had executed debug mode before. When I removed it, I could reproduce the issue – installation of my app has failed.

My app uses some APIs of Android 7.0 and 9.0, but I added checking Android versions and so it works on Android 5.0.1 as well as Android 6/7/8/9.

I suspect that **Xamarin.Android API-28 Support** module may be required to install my app.

However, it is no sense that users installs Xamarin.Android API-28 Support module first, and I cannot find the APK file of Xamarin.Android API-28 Support module.

How can I make my app installed to Android 5.0.1 and higher without installation issues?

Comment: It sounds like you have "Shared Runtime" enabled in your Release build configuration (or you are trying to deploy a Debug build)

Comment: @ SushiHangover I unchecked "Enable developer instrumentation (debugging and profiling)" and it solved. ""Enable developer instrumentation (debugging and profiling)" was checked at release mode by default. Thank you.